# Combinatorics Problem from China TST 2009, $ \frac 1{mn}{\prod_{x\in S}x}$ is square of a rational number.

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, contest-math

Let positive real numbers $ a,b$ satisfy $ b - a > 2.$ Prove that for any two distinct integers $ m,n$ belonging to $ [a,b),$ there always exists non-empty set $ S$ consisting of certain integers belonging to $ [ab,(a + 1)(b + 1))$ such that $ \frac1{mn}\displaystyle\prod_{x\in S}x$ is square of a rational number.

**I found a solution on aops as follows:**

> Let $m \sim n$ be the relation $ \frac1{mn}\displaystyle\prod_{x\in S} x$ is a rational square. I claim that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation. Denote $[ab, (a+1)(b+1))$ as $\textit{the big interval}$ henceforth, and $[a, b)$ as $\textit{the little interval}$ henceforth.
>
> Symmetry is immediate, and we can evidently prove reflexiveness by showing that there is at least one perfect square in $\textit{the big interval}$. Observe that there exists a real $0 \le r < 1$ such that $\sqrt{ab} + r$ is an integer. I claim that this, when squared, is less than $(a+1)(b+1)$. This computation is simple, observe that $$(\sqrt{ab} + r)^2 = ab + r + 2r\sqrt{ab} < ab + 1 + 2\sqrt{ab} < ab + a + b + 1 = (a+1)(b+1)$$ The next step is to show transitivity, which is slightly more nontrivial. Assume $a \sim b$ and $b \sim c$. Then, let $S_1$ be the associated set with the first one and $S_2$ be the associated set with the second one. Then, it is clear $S_1 \oplus S_2$ (where $\oplus$ denotes symmetric difference) is a working subset. (if the symmetric difference is empty, we have $ac$ perfect square, so just take the perfect square in $\textit{the big interval}$.
>
> Now that we have proven $\sim$ is simply an equivalence relation, it remains to show that all elements are equivalent to each other. Fortunately, this turns out to be not that hard. I claim that $x \sim (x+1)$ for all integers $x$ in the little interval, which will show the result by definition. This proof turns out to be rather easy; observe that $x \sim y$ if $xy$ is in $\textit{the big interval}$, for obvious reasons. So all we need to do is find an integer $y$ such that $ ab \le xy \le (x+1)y < (a+1)(b+1) $ and we will be done since $x \sim y \sim (x+1)$. This process is relatively easy. Note that we can lose here only if we have some $y$ for which
> \begin{align*}
> xy &< ab \\ 
> (x+1)(y + 1) &\ge (a+1)(b+1)
> \end{align*}
> This is of course ludicrous; subtracting the equations gives $x + y > a + b$, but $a \le x \le y < b$, so this is impossible.

**However I find the proof $x \sim (x+1)$ a bit confusing. Can anyone help me to explain.When a∈Z+ and take x equal a, there are no y satisfy the condition .Thank you very much.**

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{1}{mn}\prod_{x\in S}x$.

Comment: Yes that's what i mean

Comment: $ \frac {\displaystyle\prod_{x\in S}x}{mn}$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: There are a solution on the aops Forum using the Group Theory but it's wrong at the last part. https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h268927p1457453 (Post #5)

Comment: The solution there can be saved, by considering the missing case.

Comment: OMg I am so sorry Thanks

Comment: Don't use displaystyle in titles or mid-line. That was the reason it was hard to read your fraction as a fraction.

Comment: Sorry but the missing case it's not easy for me :( can you explain it clearly for me please Thank you very much

Comment: Sincere apologies, I'm new to latex so I don't know how to type correctly